# How to solve this error; interrupted-channel allocation requires an open connection

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I'm involving a project that using RabbitMQ as a broker between my IoT device and the consumer. After few hours of running the Python program, the following error occured.

[image]

[image]

I tried some solutions in internet but those didn't work for me.
Can someone give instructions to solve this or at least to make an open connection for the RabbitMQ.

This is my RabbitMQ part which in my Python program.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of text, post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it (usually as code to keep the line breaks and indents). Images are hard to read and impossible to search for. They are also unreadable by those that need to use a screen reader.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('admin', 'admin')
# creating connection to RabbitMQ server
Parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host='10.144.128.150', virtual_host='/', credentials=credentials)
rabbitmq_connection = pika.BlockingConnection(Parameters)  # pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
# creating channel to this connection
rabbitmq_channel = rabbitmq_connection.channel()
CONNECTION_STRING = "mongodb://10.144.128.150:27017/"